# Can any dimension be added to a SSAS CUBE dynamically

Tags: dynamic, ssas, cube, rolap

We build an SSAS ROLAP cube where data source is memSQL. The cube is built using Visual Studio 2019 and the driver used to connect to memSQL data source is "MySQL .NET Provider 8.0.19". The cube is built and processed successfully. As it is a ROLAP cube, so one of the requirement we have in our hand is to add new dimension/measure dynamically without developer intervention. Now I am looking for some expert advise, how dynamically can we add a dimension or a measure (may be through any Autosys job which will schedule to run in every hour and check for new dimension or measure).

Is it possible to do through any back-end C# code which will update the XMLA; whenever we are trying to add a new dimension or measure ?

Comment: I would recommend not doing this. You can update the xmla and redeploy it via c#, it's just XML, but how do you know it's not going to break the cube? With out processing and testing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good example code at [Analysis Services Cube Programatically/Automatically Generated via c# and AMO](http://avinashkt.blogspot.com/2008/04/olap-cube-generation-programmatically.html)

This helped me to build a code for dynamic cube using memSQL as data source.